# Makefile :*** unterminated call to function `foreach': missing `)'. Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am getting above error when i execute my target. I have terminated the foreach with a closing brace but still it persists.

```
$(addprefix c_lr, $(RLRG_LRGS)):c_lr%:
        $(foreach i, $(days), \ 
        if [ "$(day)" = "$(i)" ] ; then \
        $(ECHO) This is a valid . ; \
        fi ; \
        )
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using TAB instead of space?

Comment: Yes i am using tabs only

Answer (score 2):

On the first recipe line, there is a space after the backslash:

```
        $(foreach i, $(days), \ 
                               ^---space here
```

A backslash only escapes a newline if the newline comes directly after the backslash.  If there's a space after the backslash, then it's not an escaped newline, it's just a backslash followed by a space.

I highly recommend using an editor (such as GNU Emacs) that has a good Makefile editing mode with the ability to highlight questionable whitespace.  This makes it easy to find mistakes like that.